# Z3 - Floating point arithmetic API function Z3_mk_fpa_to_ubv

Tags: c++, floating-point, z3

I am playing around with Z3-4.6.0 C++ for the first time. Sorry for the noob questions.

My question has 2 parts.

If I have a floating point number, and I use **Z3_mk_fpa_to_ubv(...)** function to create an unsigned bit-vector.

1. How much precision is lost?
2. If the precision is not lost, can I use this new unsigned bit-vector as a regular bit-vector and apply all operations defined for it for e.g., **Z3_mk_bvadd(....)**?

I know I can use **Z3_mk_fpa_to_ieee_bv(....)** for graceful, and IEEE-754 compliant conversion. Afterwards I can add,sub etc the bit-vectors.

Just being curious.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you're misinterpreting the role of these functions. A good reference to keep open while working with SMTLib floats is: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/BTRW15.pdf

## mk_fpa_to_ubv

This function corresponds to the `FPToUInt` function in the cited paper. It's defined as follows:

[image: FPToUInt]

(The NaN choice above is misleading: It should be read as "undefined.")

Note that the precision loss can be huge here, depending on what the FP value is and the bit-width of the vector. Imagine converting a double-precision floating point value to an 8-bit word: You're smashing values in the range ±2.23×10^−308 to ±1.80×10^308 to a mere 256 different values. This means a large number of conversions simply will go through massive rounding cancelations.

You should think of this as "casting" in C like languages:

```
unsigned char c;
double f;
c = (char) f;
```

This is the essence of conversion from double-precision to unsigned byte, which will suffer major precision loss. In the other direction, if you convert to a really large bit-vector (say one that has a thousand bits), then your conversion will still be losing precision per the rounding mode, though you'll be able to cover all the integer values precisely in the range. So, it really depends on what BV-type you convert to and the rounding mode you choose.

## mk_fpa_to_ieee_bv

This function has nothing to do with "preserving" the value. So asking "precision loss" here is irrelevant. What it does is that it gives you the underlying bit-vector representation of the floating-point value, per the IEEE-754 spec. The wikipedia article has a good discussion on this representation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64

In particular, if you interpret the output of this function as a two's complement integer value, you'll get a completely irrelevant value that has nothing to do with the value of the floating-point number itself. (Also, this conversion is not unique since NaN has multiple corresponding bit-vector patterns.)

## Summary

Long story short, conversions from floats to bit-vectors will suffer from precision loss not only due to losing the "fractional" part due to rounding, but also due to the limited range, unless you pick a very-large bit-vector size. The IEEE-754 representation conversion does *not* preserve value, and thus doing arithmetic on values converted via this function is more or less meaningless.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, and pointing me to the literature. It answers my queries, and confusions which I had. You also clarified mk_fpa_to_ieee_bv function, which I was planning to use for FPA. So, I think I will stick to reals in that case, instead of converting everything to bit-vectors.

Comment: Minor detail: `mk_fpa_to_ieee_bv` is a Z3-specific extension and it is neither IEEE754 nor SMT compliant. It produces only a single NaN bit-vector, so use with care.